# Collision Detection with Squares in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently working on a program where a square is chasing another square, once the squares touch each other how do I detect that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is collision detection code for pygame:

```
if square1.is_collided_with(square2):
    print('collision!')
```